# jQuery animate table from json2html transform

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, json2html

I cannot animate with CSS3 because the properties are not yet standard across browsers.

I can create a div table with json2html.

I can `animate` a row by setting `{height:(toggle)?'show':'hide', opacity: (toggle)?1:0}, function(){ $(this).css('display', (toggle)?'auto':'none').css('height', ) }` with jQuery to make rows appear and disappear.

What I cannot do is put them together.  [I've seen the json2html examples (Examples->jquery)](http://json2html.com/), and they apply functions, but even if I understood how the functions are being applied, I'd still have no idea how to incorporate animate.

How can jQuery `$.aniamte()` be called on a json2html constructed element from a json2html transform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figure this is a little old but worth commenting on ..

json2html maps attributes with the starting characters "on" to events, so

onclick -> jquery event "click"
 onfocus -> jquery event "focus"

which uses the function $.on( event,...) to register the event.  This means you can use any event that $.on() recognizes.  [For more documentation on $.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

Since strictly speaking $.animate isn't an event, but rather a jquery function you won't be able to use it with the json2html.

Comment: Yep, should've deleted this after your awesome primer on `eventData` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313664/json2html-eventdata-example